# Google Mail API Error: 'Account has been deleted error'

Tags: gmail-api, access-token

When we try to get a accessToken for a user for the Google Mail API via the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token endpoint we get an error

> 'Account has been deleted error'.

This works fine for all users but one.  Before last week also for this user everything worked find.  When I check the Users in de Google Workspace Admin Console the user and email address still exists and is active.

What can be the cause of this error?

We tried the same with other users in the organisation and these work just fine.

Comment: welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Are you trying to get the access token using a refresh token? If the user was deleted and restored or if the email was remade the refresh token could have been invalidated. Try to reauthorize the user if this is the case.